# Tablix Matrix - Chart Spanning Multiple Rows

Tags: matrix, charts, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm using a SSRS 2008 R2 Tablix control to display a matrix. Columns display date groupings (e.g. year, quarter). Each row displays a statistic about a particular item. Example:

```
      2010                    2011
      Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q1
ABC   25    16    81    12    13
DFF    8    -2    11    10    19
```

I'd like to display a per-item graph giving a visual representation of the numerical statics. Example:

```
      2010                    2011
      Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q1
ABC   25    16    81    12    13
      { chart for item ABC goes here and spans across all date rows }
DFF    8    -2    11    10    19
      { chart for item DFF goes here and spans across all date rows }
```

Is there a way for me to insert a chart control so that it spans the date grouping columns? Is there another way I could achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to Create a "Dynamic detail row" for each group.

More on how to create one here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220587.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this thought. My problem is that I want the detail row to span several columns. I don't think that a dynamic detail row supports that.